# VLC (J) audio pitch control

Tags: java, swing, audio, pitch, vlcj

I'm currently developing simple video player with VLCJ. 
Can anyone please point me some clue about changing audio pitch with it? 
is it possible?

I've searching through but cannot find the right keyword, what i need is
some control (method/function) of vlcj (or any) to increase sound so it sounds like
kids voice, or lower down so make like a very old man sound.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE:
still looking on google but found nothing about vlc. what i want is something about the "timbre" as explained at http://www.screamingbee.com/support/morphdoc/MorphDocPitchTimbre.aspx

Comment: Do you simply need to change the playback rate of samples, or are you trying to change pitch while keeping tempo?

Comment: i am user who ask this. i think i want to change pitch while keeping tempo. well, i think it has something to do with frequency.

Comment: If you are using two accounts, you can request that they be [merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/163188).

Comment: @trashgod, sorry but i'm not using 2 accounts. lee is my froend and last night my laptop was out of battery, so i'm posting from his account. sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in playing audio (you don't care about displaying any video at the same time) then vlcj 2.4.0 and later provide a so-called "direct" audio player component.

With this component, your Java application can get direct access to the native audio sample buffer. You can run whatever algorithm you want on those samples, then play out your modified samples via JavaSound or some other API.

There is a sample included in the vlcj distribution that shows how to use this component to play via JavaSound:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/tree/vlcj-2.4.1/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/directaudio

The example does not show how to change the pitch of the audio, but it does show how to use the direct audio player.